# Change the font size in the RStudio user interface (not graphs etc.) under Linux

Tags: r, rstudio

This is *not* a question about changing the font size in graphs produced using RStudio. I already know how to do that.

I use RStudio under Linux on a MacBook Pro with a 'retina' display. I use KDE as my window manager. I can (and do) enlarge the default font size in the user interface of other programs in KDE. I increase the font size for the user interface in Firefox and Thunderbird using program specific tools.

How do I increase the font size in the *user interface* - not the console, which is easy [Options -> Appearance -> font size], but, for example, the help text, the keyboard shortcuts list, and so on. At the moment I find these very hard to read. I've fiddled with everything I can fiddle with, but had no joy.

All help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: For Help pane: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41022568/1009306

Answer (score 11):

As some people pointed out, by clicking the **ctrl** & **+** together, you can enlarge the font size for everything including for the console & code script. (You will have to do it with a help page pop up as suggested by user3619015.) Then go to the global option and resize the fonts. That changes the font size for everything except the help page. So you will have larger fonts for the help page but everything else in your normal preferred font size.

Comment: Yes! cmd & + in Mac Os X

Comment: That seems to be the only valid work-around in place.
First increase everything, then "show in new window" i.e. strip out the window you wanna keep in the larger view, then decrease (zoom out) the whole Rstudio app again. 
Tedious but until the Rstudio guys invent seperate zoom factors for each pane we will have to live with this, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac you can do it by going to: **view -> actual size** or just with the key combo: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> (not <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) to zoom in (bigger), <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> or zoom out or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (zero) to go back to the actual size.

Answer (score 2):

Rstudio doesn't support changing fonts yet, at least for Linux server. However, one can change fonts in browser for a specific page. At least in chrome, you can customize fonts using an extension called font changer. I think it is packed with all GNU free fonts for legal issues. But, since you have the font files in the OS, like consolas, you can practically change to whatever font and size you like. Just play with it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here using a MacBook Pro although not with KDE, but you could try on the menu of RStudio:

View -> Actual size

After a couple of days struggling to read the help, this worked: increased the size of letters in all windows of RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

Help, Files, Packages can be opened in a new browser window where zoom in and out options are possible. Even a selected specific package can be opened in a new window for clear view[image: Please check the image]

Comment: Really good suggestion, but, at least on Linux with Version 0.98.953 –  (Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio Safari/534.34 Qt/4.8.5) I can't make it work. A new window indeed opens, but I cannot see any way to increase the font size on this window. The usual Ctrl-+ does not work, and resizing the window does not increase the font size at all. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Same here, doesn't work on a windows environment either.

Comment: It works perfectly for windows environment. As you select the symbol indicated above you will be directed to IE browser where you can use zoom in ctlr +, zoom out ctrl - options

Comment: @user3619015 On Windows 7, click that button, RStudio won't open the docs in a browser - it opens a new window of its own. No zoom in/out support. What's your Windows version? Or are theere any related settings in RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

While this is quite an old question, you can now also change your font size under Linux like that:

`Tools` -> `Global Options...` -> `Appearance` -> `Editor font size`

Comment: OP mentions this as NOT the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I got around the problem:

Simply copy and paste into your word processor or text editor.  Text will be pasted in the default text.

I'm using Windows 8.1, Office 2013 and R 64 bit.  Not optimal but it works.