# How do I increase font size in RStudio Help pane?

Tags: rstudio

I  use glasses for presbyopia, and can read all other panes, but often have to open R for help, because of its bigger font size, although I find it inconvenient.

I haven't found any answer in support.rstudio.com ; somebody else asked this same question in 2014.

I am using a MacBook Air with macOS Sierra 10.12.1, RStudio 1.0.44 and R 3.3.2

Thanks!

Comment: As of 2021, there is now a global help option, see answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66625204/180892

Answer (score 19):

Open **"...\RStudio\resources\R.css"** file in your RStudio installation folder with a text editor. In the beginning of the file you will see:

```
body, td {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 10pt;
}
```

That is the setting you are looking for. Change **font-size** to anything you want.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! For mac users out there, R.css is in "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources" - you'll need to right-click on the RStudio application in.., well, the Applications folder, and select "Show Package Contents". Then follow the rest of the path

Comment: It's obvious R studio is made by math wizards, not by web developers. "pt" is a metric used for print. On paper sizes don't scale and zoom. On screens they do, and actual font size depends on screen size, resolution and pixel density. Thus, px, em, % and vw are much more apt for resizable text.

Paper is often much bigger than the screens we read today. 10pt on a regular A4 paper, printed on a quality printer is very legible. 10pt on a small phone screen with high resolution is completely illegible.

Comment: Excellent. In case it helps others: If you face "access denied" when saving the modified file, first open Notepad in admin mode and then open the css file from within that Notepad instance.

Comment: @rszengin: unfortunately R.css file editing in Windows10 (Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042) doesn't work for RStudio v. 1.3.1073. Any thoughts?

Comment: This will not work with more recent versions of RStudio. See my answer below

Answer (score 10):

This feature is now implemented on RStudio since version 1.3, as tracked on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3282).

Modify font size in:
Tools -> Global options -> General -> Advanced -> Help panel font size

Comment: after trying to read the help pane my eyes couldn't see your WORKING ANSWER  : ) !!! Thanks a lot. (Some time ago modification of R.css file worked for me but afterwards did not!)

Comment: This is great, thanks robertspierre. I would've thought it would make more sense to have the help panel font size in the same place as the editor font size, i.e. Tools > Global Options > Appearance. :-O

Comment: This does, indeed, change the font size of RStudio's help, but frustratingly doesn't change the font size of text in vignettes, which are also displayed in the help viewer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can specifically resize the help window font size in the way you can with the other windows. You can resize the whole of RStudio using **View** -> **Zoom In** or else **Tools** -> **Global Options** -> **Appearance** and change the **Zoom** there. Both of these will resize everything in R Studio so you may want to readjust your font size afterwards if you'd previously increased it.

Comment: I’m afraid both work... for all panes, except the Help pane. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to work for me, both ways, [here is 100% on the left and 200% on the right](http://imgur.com/a/QUmeG).

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, now you can go to Preference -> General -> Advanced -> Help panel font size