# RStudio Data Viewer: Change Font Size

Tags: css, rstudio, font-size

In RStudio, how can I change the font-size of the Data Viewer (the table that appears every time we use `utils::View()`)

I'm using Windows 10 64bit.

I'm almost sure there should be a CSS file in Program Files which I could change the font size parameter.
I have successfully changed the Help pane font size changing the R.css file in Program Files ([How do I increase font size in RStudio Help pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022568/how-do-i-increase-font-size-in-rstudio-help-pane))

I have been playing with the Web Inspector but I couldn't figured out which CSS file is the Viewer using. It seems that the CSS specifications are created on the fly every time View() is called.

According to this 3-year-old post is not possible (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206375098-Data-Frame-Font-Sizes).

I have played with Windows Fonts zoom functions. However, this doesn't solve the problem because it changes font-size for all applications, I'm using other applications apart from RStudio.